# com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETException: Initialization did not complete in a timely fashion

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, push

I'm putting together an Android application to demo Mobile Push.  I've followed all of the relevant steps, but now when I run the application I get the following exception:

```
com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETException: Initialization did not complete in a timely fashion.
```

The error occurs on this line

```
 ETPush pushManager = ETPush.pushManager();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Paul